# Vertical alignment BETWEEN fieldsets

Tags: html, css

I have two `FIELDSET`s, each having `TABLE` within the `FORM`, with one having text in the end.  Those `FIELDSET`s are aligned like the picture below:

[image]

Is it possible to vertically align those fieldsets, so the `LEGEND`s are aligned?

MWE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <fieldset style="display:inline-block;">
    <legend>First settings</legend>
    <form method="POST" action="/ames">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A1</td>
          <td><input name="A1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A2</td>
          <td><input name="A2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data A3</td>
          <td><input name="A3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2"><button>Update settings</button></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset style="display:inline-block;">
    <legend>Second settings</legend>
    <form method="POST" action="/lang">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Data B1</td>
          <td><input name="B1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data B2</td>
          <td><input name="B2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data B3</td>
          <td><input name="B3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2"><button>Update settings</button></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    Change accepted.
  </fieldset>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `vertical-align:top` to your elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex box` model for this. Just have the `body` display `flex`. You can also wrap the `fieldset` elements in a div and have that parent element display `flex` instead if there are other items on your page that you do not want in the flex container.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>


<fieldset>
<legend>First settings</legend>
<form method="POST" action="/ames">
<table>
  <tr><td>Data A1</td><td><input name="A1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data A2</td><td><input name="A2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data A3</td><td><input name="A3"></td></tr>
  <tr><th colspan="2"><button>Update settings</button></th></tr>
</table>
</form>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Second settings</legend>
<form method="POST" action="/lang">
<table>
  <tr><td>Data B1</td><td><input name="B1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data B2</td><td><input name="B2"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data B3</td><td><input name="B3"></td></tr>
  <tr><th colspan="2"><button>Update settings</button></th></tr>
</table>
</form>
Change accepted.
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```